# Dealing with numeric and character elements (in one variable) in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have this data set:

```
> mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,67,7,8,9), value=c(2,6,23,77,2,"e",4,5,"f"))
> mydata
  id value
1  1     2
2  2     6
3  3    23
4  4    77
5  5     2
6 67     e
7  7     4
8  8     5
9  9     f
```

I need to divide mydata$value by 2 if its numeric or leave it as is if not. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you have character and numeric values both in the same column? That makes R very sad.

Comment: I know :(. That's how the data was entered... now I need tot deal with it :), the character also have meaning in here.

Comment: Well, you should separate the characters with meaning out from the numeric values. Mostly likely now you have a factor variable. If you want to convert that to numeric, you'd need to do `as.numeric(as.character(mydata$value))`; that will return `NA` for non-numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
mydata$value <- as.character(mydata$value)
with(mydata, ifelse(grepl('^-?[0-9.]+$',value), as.numeric(value)/2, value))
#[1] "1"    "3"    "11.5" "38.5" "1"    "e"    "2"    "2.5"  "f"
```

Testing with other cases (as @Carl Witthoft mentioned in the comments)

```
foo<-c(1,3, "hi4u",7, -42)
grepl('^-?[0-9.]+$',foo)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I guess, I have to make some modifications for that case.

Comment: Nice fix (I think :-) ). No go poke holes in my method!

Answer (score 3):

First, shoot the genius who built the data this way.  Then, consider using a search like

```
mynums <- which (!(mydata$value%in%letters))
mydata$value[mynums] <- mydata$value[mynums]/2
```

I need to torture-test this method,seeing as I already picked on akrun for possible gaps in his solution.